# Trying to create a searchview controller that only shows results after user hits enter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a search page in my iOS app, which returns zero rows at first, but after the user taps on the search bar, types in what they are searching for and hits enter (return) only then will the results populate the rows. I keep trying to get this to work but to no avail :(. I keep getting an uncaught exception. Here is the code, what am i doing wrong??

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)_searchBar {
    isSearched = YES;

    //NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;

    NSPredicate *searchResults = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username contains[c] %@", _searchBar.text];
    self.searchedUsers = [self.allUsers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchResults];

    NSLog(@"%@",[self.searchedUsers objectAtIndex:0]);


    [self.tableView reloadData];


    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)_searchBar {
    isSearched = NO;
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.searchedUsers count];
    } else {
        return 0;//[self.allUsers count];
    }
}
```

This is the uncaught exception that i get:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for rect at invalid index path ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})'.

I get this error as soon as i start typing in the search field.

Comment: In your code, you are not yet implementing all the required delegate and datasource uitableview protocol methods. Refer to the tableview datasource and tableview delegate docs for more infos.

Comment: I implemented them, Im only showing the ones that deal with showing the rows, because I am assuming that is where the problem lies